# Getting "connect_error due to xhr poll error" while connecting socket server

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to connect socket.io client which inside react app to the socket.io server but i am getting xhr poll error. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong? client & server code is as follow:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';


const socket = io("ws://loacalhost:5000");

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
```

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(require('cors')());
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);


const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

  console.log(socket.id)
})

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on Port 5000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok in server file as well as everything is ok in client file except there is syntax mistake in client code i.e.

```
const socket = io("ws://loacalhost:5000");
```

replaced with:

```
const socket = io("ws://localhost:5000");
```

then it is worked fine, successfully connected to server

Answer (score 0):

Your localhost spelling is incorrect.

```
const socket = io("ws://loacalhost:5000");
```

Replaced with

```
const socket = io("ws://localhost:5000");
```